# SQL How to sum values of the same column until a threshold/condition is met?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

## Edit - I am using MSSQL Server 2005 - SP4 (9.0.5000)

I have 3 columns in a table - Customer ID, Order Number, Payment Date, and Payment. When a user makes a payment, it logs data using the Customer ID, increments the order number (so the first payment is 1, second payment is 2, etc), and has a date and payment amount.

**I only want to query all the first payments made until the total payment amount reaches a threshold/condition of 100.**

First I tried just working with sum() to see if something would just magically pop into my head - but total sums are all I know how to do:

```
select CustomerID, Order, sum(Payment) as FirstFullPayment
from #temp
group by CustomerID
```

Then I tried making 2 different temporary tables - #up for unfinished payments and #fp for finished payments. My thinking is that I can put the confirmed >100 payments into #fp, and put the confirmed unfinished payments into #up with something like this:

```
select * into #fp
from #temp
where Order = 1 and Payment >= 100

select * into #up
from #temp
where Order = 1 and Payment < 100
```

Then I could sequentially join #up and #temp where Order = 2, 3, 4, etc., add the Payments in #up until they are >= 100, then insert them into #fp

The only thing is I know this is a very bad and roundabout method, and there must be a better and simpler way to do this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 9.0.5000

Comment: Are payments always positive amounts?

Comment: Yes, they are always postive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use running sums and select the row you by your criteria: <=100

```
select top 1 * from 
    (
    select CustomerID,  
                (
                SELECT SUM(b.payment)
                           FROM #temp b
                           WHERE a.customerid=b.customerID and  b.[order] <= a.[order]) as FirstFullPayment
    from #temp a
    --where customerid=yourCustomerId
    )runningsums
where runningsums.FirstFullPayment<=100
order by runningsums.FirstFullPayment desc
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries work, but they always hurt my brain. Can you add a max(Order) to return the "last" Order, on the off-chance they need it?

Comment: @Tudor You rock ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that none of the payments can be negative so that the cumulative sum will also be an increasing series (monotonic). Here's one way to do it if you want the cumulative total and order number at the point it crosses the threshold:

```
select CustomerID, min(OrderNumber), min(CumulativePayments)
from
(
    select
        CustomerID, OrderNumber,
        (
            select sum(t2.Payment) from T t2
            where t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID and t2.OrderNumber <= t.OrderNumber
        ) as CumulativePayments
   from T t
) cp
where CumulativePayments >= 100
group by CustomerID
```

**EDIT:** If you need *all* the data and rows *up to* the point of the threshold:

```
select * from T t
where OrderNumber <=
(
    select min(OrderNumber)
    from
    (
        select
            OrderNumber,
            (
                select sum(t3.Payment) from T t3
                where t3.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID and t3.OrderNumber <= t2.OrderNumber
            ) as CumulativePayments
        from T t2
        where t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
    ) cp
    where CumulativePayments >= 100
)
```

These approaches don't rely on `row_number()` or `sum() over (...)` or `top n...order by`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using common table expressions (which were introduced with SQL 2005):

```
;WITH cteBaseline
 as (--  For each customer, for each order, get sum of payments for all
     --  orders less than or equal to "this" order, where the total is
     --  within the desired range
     select
        te.CustomerId
       ,te.Order
       ,sum(subset.Payment) TotalPayment
      from #temp te
       inner join #temp subset
        on subset.CustomerId <= te.CustomerId
      group by
        te.CustomerId
       ,te.Order
      having sum(subset.Payment) < 100  --  Make this a parameter to control the "breakpoint"
     )
--  Get the "last" row
select
   cte.CustomerId
  ,cte.Order
  ,cte.TotalPayment
 from cteBaseline cte
  inner join (--  get the "last" row, the one with the largest TotalPayment
              select
                 CustomerId
                ,max(Order)
               from cteBaseline
               group by CustomerId) xx
   on xx.CustomerId = cte.CustomerId
    and xx.Order = cte.Order
```

You'd want to double-check the syntax. Also, depending on table size and indexes this might perform poorly, as there's a lot of joining going on.